# Show that if all points in space lie in a collection of subbasic open sets, all points lie in two of the subbasic open sets

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\{0,1\}^A$ be the collection of functions from an index set $A$ to $\{0,1\}$. Having subbasis $\{U(a,\delta)|a \in A,\delta \in \{0,1\}\},U(a,0)=\pi_{a}^{-1}(0),U(a,1)=\pi_{a}^{-1}(1)$.Show if a collection of subbasic open sets of $\{0,1\}^A$ has the property that every point of $\{0,1\}^A$ lies in at least one of those subbasic open sets, then there are two subbasic open sets in that collection such that every point of $\{0,1\}^A$ lies in one of those subbasic sets.

Attempt:Let $S$ be such a collection of subbasic sets. If $\{0,1\}^A \in S$. There is nothing to show. Suppose $\{0,1\}^A \notin S$.Then there are two subbasic sets $\pi_{a_1}^{-1}(b_1),\pi_{a_2}^{-1}(b_2),b_i \in \{0,1\},a_1\neq a_2$ in $S$. Then $\pi_{a_1}^{-1}(b_1)\cup\pi_{a_2}^{-1}(b_2)=\{0,1\}^A$, since the only factor of $\pi_{a_1}^{-1}(b_1)$ with points restricted to either $0$ or $1$ is the $a_1$'st factor. And the only factor of $ \pi_{a_2}^{-1}(b_2)$ with points restricted to $0$ or $1$ is the $a_2$'nd factor. So the union must contain all points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case in your proof is impossible: $\{0,1\}^A$ is not one of the sets $U(a,\delta)$ with $a\in A$ and $\delta\in\{0,1\}$, so by definition $\{0,1\}^A\notin S$. The argument in your second case is simply incomprehensible. If it were correct, the union of **any** two members of $S$ would be $\{0,1\}^A$, which certainly need not be the case: $S$ might contain $U(a_1,0)$, $U(a_2,0)$, and $U(a_2,1)$ for distinct $a_1,a_2\in A$, and

$$U(a_1,0)\cup U(a_2,0)\ne\{0,1\}^A\,:$$

for instance, $U(a_1,0)\cup U(a_2,0)$ does not contain the function that is $1$ on every element of $A$. Of course in this case $U(a_2,0)\cup U(a_2,1)$ **is** $\{0,1\}^A$, but your argument applies to **any** two members of $S$, not to some carefully chosen pair.

In fact $U(a_1,\delta_1)\cup U(a_2,\delta_2)=\{0,1\}^A$ if and only if $a_1=a_2$ and $\delta_1\ne\delta_2$.

- Prove this.

Thus, if $S$ does not contain two members whose union is $\{0,1\}^A$, then for each $a\in A$ it must contain at most one of the sets $U(a,0)$ and $U(a,1)$. This means that for each $a\in A$ there is a $\delta_a\in\{0,1\}$ such that $U(a,\delta_a)\notin S$. Define $x\in\{0,1\}^A$ by letting $x(a)=\delta_a$ for each $a\in A$.

- Prove that $x\notin\bigcup S$.

Conclude that if $S$ does not contain two members whose union is $\{0,1\}^A$, then $\bigcup S\ne\{0,1\}^A$, and hence that if $\bigcup S=\{0,1\}^A$, then $S$ contains both $U(a,0)$ and $U(a,1)$ for some $a\in A$ and hence contains two subbasic open sets whose union is $\{0,1\}^A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be any cover of $\{0,1\}^A$ by subbasic sets $U(a,\delta)$.
Define for each $S \in \mathcal{S}$, $a(S) \in A$ and $\delta(S) \in \{0,1\}$ so that $S=U(a(S), \delta(S))$. Define $$A' = \{a(S)\mid S \in \mathcal{S}\}$$ the set of all $a$ that are used in $\mathcal{S}$, and for $a \in A'$, define $$r(a):=\{\delta \in \{0,1\} \mid \exists S' \in \mathcal{S}: a(S')=a, \delta(S')=\delta\}$$

the range in $\{0,1\}$ that is used, per used index $a$, always non-empty.

If $r(a)=\{0,1\}$ for some $a$ we are done, because then $U(a,0), U(a,1) \in \mathcal{S}$ and their union is $\{0,1\}^A$.

So striving for a contradiction we assume that for all $a \in A'$ we have $|r(a)|=1$. But then define

$f \in \{0,1\}^A$ by

$$f(a)= \begin{cases} 0 & a \notin A'\\
                      1-\delta & r(a)=\{\delta\}\\
        \end{cases}$$

But then $f \notin \bigcup \mathcal{S}$ and we have the required contradiction already. So *some* $r(a)=\{0,1\}$ etc.

Sidenote: note that this shows that $\{0,1\}^A$ is compact by Alexander's subbase lemma, and even *supercompact*:

> A space $X$ is called supercompact if it has a subbase $\mathcal{S}$ for its topology such that every cover from $\mathcal{S}$ has a subcover of $2$ elements.

This notion was studied in the 70's and 80's (a Dutch hobby perhaps, van Douwen and van Mill wrote about it); it is well-known that products of supercompact spaces are supercompact, and all metrisable compact spaces and ordered compact spaces are supercompact. $\beta \Bbb N$ is not however.